# Can we solve this kind of 0-1 Multiple Knapsack problem in DP?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

The problem is: given a set of n items and a set of m knapsacks, c[i] is the capacity of knapsack i, w[j] is the weight of item j, p[i][j] is the profit of put item j to the knapsack i, that means an item may have different profit if placing in different knapsack.

We have to find the optimal solution to make the total profit of the selected items is a maximum and all the selected items have to be placed in the same knapsack. For example, if there are two knapsacks A and B, the final solution cannot be placing some items in A and placing some items in B. All the selected items must be either placed in A or placed in B. So this question is somewhat different from the traditional 0-1 Multiple knapsack problem.

One solution is breaking this multiple knapsack problem into multiple small 0-1 knapsack problem. For each knapsack, we can use dynamic programming to solve the 0-1 knapsack problem and find the maximum profit for this knapsack. Use the same algorithm to traverse all the knapsacks and select the maximum profit，we can get the solution we want.

I want to know, is there any better method with better time complexity to solve this problem? Or any dynamic programming method to avoid traversing all the knapsacks? If there is no better way, how to prove?

Comment: This is obviously best-possible, unless there is some useful structure to the knapsacks (e.g. if we know that *every* item has the same or lower value in knapsack #2 than it does in knapsack #1, *and* knapsack #2 has the same or lower capacity than knapsack #1 does, there is no need to consider knapsack #2 at all).

Comment: The best solution is using DP to find the best profit for each knapsack, then traverse all the knapsacks? How to prove this is the best or not?

Comment: I went a bit too far -- it's only best-possible on the assumption that whichever algorithm (e.g. the standard DP) is used as a subroutine to solve each contained Knapsack instance is best-possible; I don't know whether that is actually the case or not.

Comment: Proof sketch: The time complexity of this algorithm is O(sum_i(T_i)), where T_i is the time needed to solve the i-th individual knapsack instance using the best known algorithm.  Suppose an asymptotically faster algorithm existed, with time o(sum_i(T_i)): Notice that this same algorithm is capable of solving a single knapsack instance, and in that case is necessarily faster than the best known algorithm for solving a sufficiently large single knapsack instance.